# ReactJS: Using state causes error rendering heading

Tags: reactjs, axios

`console.log()` inside `componentDidMount()` works with no problem.
This works as expected with logging working correctly:
[image: working console.log]

Here is the problem; inside return for `App` it's not letting me render the `<h1>`:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />,
        <h1>{this.state.users.data[0].images.original.webp}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[image]
This code however works without `< h1>`:

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
    import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
    import "./App.css";
    import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    loading: false
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    const res = await axios.get(
      "http://api.giphy.com/v1/stickers/search?q=monster&api_key=sIycZNSdH7EiFZYhtXEYRLbCcVmUxm1O"
    );

    this.setState({ users: res.data, loading: false });
    console.log(123);
    console.log(this.state.users.data[0].images.original.webp);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Please help me understand why this is happening

Comment: you should display this.state.users.data[0].images only when "users" has data. Else it will throw error on initial render.

Comment: This question is related to component lifecycle of React, in order to improve your ReactJS skill, you must understand full on how component lifecycle works. Recommending this: https://hackernoon.com/reactjs-component-lifecycle-methods-a-deep-dive-38275d9d13c0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that the `users` data is present in your component's state before attempting to access and render it (ie in your `<h1>` element).

Keep in mind that the [component's `render()` method will be called before `componentDidMount()`](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) (ie before the network request has completed). This means you'll need to account for `users` data not being present in your component's rendering logic. Consider making the following changes to your component to solve this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: null, /* Set users inital state to null */
    loading: false
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    const res = await axios.get(
      "http://api.giphy.com/v1/stickers/search?q=monster&api_key=sIycZNSdH7EiFZYhtXEYRLbCcVmUxm1O"
    );

    /* Trigger re-render. The users data will now be present in 
       component state and accessible for use/rendering */
    this.setState({ users: res.data, loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <Navbar />
       { /* If state.users is null, show loading string, otherwise render data */ }
       <h1> 
       { this.state.users === null ? "Loading" : 
         this.state.users.data[0].images.original.webp }
       </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this because the `this.state.users` is empty array at the first time , when the component mount  http request sent and when the response is ready you change the state .

to fix the issue do this :

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />,
        {
             this.state.user.length > 0 ?
                 <h1>{this.state.users.data[0].images.original.webp}</h1>
             :
                 <h1>Loading...</h1>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```